# Open a page without loading using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this webpage i made,just to get started with web, based on this template.

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/#

where on clicking the thumbnails in portfolio, another webpage opens with more details on the picture. The code i have written is making the page load. I want to implement it exactly as in this template.

html (for thumbnails) :

```
<div class = "pictures ">
            <div class = "container ">
                <div >

                    <center><b><text>PORTFOLIO</text></b></center>
                </div>
                <div class = "pics">
                  <div class = "column">
                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img data-src = "glass.png" src = "cabin.png" id="cabin" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img data-src="glass.png" src = "cake.png" id="cake" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class = "column">
                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img  data-src = "glass.png" src = "circus.png" id="circus" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img data-src="glass.png" src = "game.png" id="game" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "column">
                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img data-src="glass.png" src = "safe.png" id="safe" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img data-src="glass.png" src = "submarine.png" id="submarine" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery for opening new page :

```
$(".pictures .thumbnail img").click ( function () {
                    window.location.href = this.id +".html";

                });
```

What changes should i make to my code which allows me to open pages without loading/refreshing?

thanks in advance!

Comment: it's a long process, you need to start reading about **jquery ajax()** and you'll learn how to do it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "open a page without loading or refreshing"?

Comment: The page you linked uses modals (Bootstrap modals: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: You could also fetch data and pre-render html before switching it into you application. This means you are not actually changing site (not chaning URI), just changing the HTML. This can be done in many different ways, but not all are efficient.

Comment: just write the content of what you want to open in next page in a division then make it display none and on clicking it, make display none division to display. this will be like opening page with out loading. inspect the page you were mentioning. you will come to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn some AJAX to achieve this. Read the [jQuery Docs on AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info.

**Ajax** is a client-side script that communicates to and from a server/database *without the need for a postback or a complete page refresh*. The best definition I've read for Ajax is “the method of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the entire page.” Source: [Seguetech](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjABahUKEwiyrIjOo-zGAhVEJh4KHU8eBog&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seguetech.com%2Fblog%2F2013%2F03%2F12%2Fwhat-is-ajax-and-where-is-it-used-in-technology&ei=NUKuVfK9E8TMeM-8mMAI&usg=AFQjCNHD8bBXULbWgGg1U2wLwCHqMOnIXA&sig2=s6HKL_ZnNq2hFoqrUP4OAA&bvm=bv.98197061,d.dmo)

Here is some example AJAX and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

        $("#loadingimg").show();

        $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){                          
                $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
                $("#loadingimg").hide();                    
            }           
        });    

    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/)

---

Be dauntless. It looks sort of confusing, especially just starting with jQuery, but trust me it isn't. You'll be glad you learned it.

Comment: Thank you :) I guess i will come back once i know ajax a bit!

Answer (score 2):

The template you are referring to uses *bootstrap modals*. Also to get data on the fly to fill the modal you need to know Ajax. Boy Wonder already gave a definition. But you can also populate the modal without getting data from the server site, it can be static after all. You can learn about bootstrap modals from here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals